# Backer Boards Around Bathtub

Tags: bathtub, backer-board

I am remodeling a bathroom and I am wondering whether or not I am to cut the backerboard so that it runs behind the tub or just up to the edge of the tub. Whichever is the answer I'd appreciate a description on why.  Thanks.

Comment: thanks,  I agree.  I am on the phone app and can't find how to remove it

Comment: No worries ; ). The community will close it out for you, good luck with your tile job!

Comment: @aguertin You can't delete from the app (very sad) but if you log in via a browser you can delete it yourself